# AngularJS Need help on providing routeProvider when for url having jsessionid

Tags: angularjs

I've a URL like

```
http://localhost:8080/main/do/myPage;jsessionid=vEuUTi2Ac5nPzP5R1-5bt81Y.tf
```

How to give RouteProvider?  I tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$routeProvider.when('/main/do/myPage/:extraParam?', {
}
```

Comment: You sure there's a semi-colon in the URL? Usually it's a question mark

Comment: yes, there is a sem-colon.  The server is appending jsessionid to the url with a semi-colon only.